# Barchart Colour Boolean

Tags: r

There are many very similar questions to this one but not this specific question.
I want to assign colour to my barchart based on a boolean rather than as I've done it in the example.
Subsequently I want to give the barchart a legend using that boolean.
Can you help?  Code below:-

```
## Barchart Example Question
## Improve Colours
## Legend Required where data1 red, etc

data1 <- c(8,9,7.5,8.2)
data2 <- c(3.8, 6.3, 5)
data3 <- c(2.2, 8.8, 9.5, 7.4, 6.2)

barplot(c(data1,data2,data3), main="Three Data Sources Compared",
        names.arg = seq(1:length(c(data1,data2,data3))),
        col= c("red","red","red","red",
               "blue","blue","blue",
               "green","green","green","green","green"))
```

[image: the barchart from the above code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `c`oncatenate the vectors into a named vector.

```
(dat <- c(data1=data1, data2=data2, data3=data3))
# data11 data12 data13 data14 data21 data22 data23 data31 data32 data33 data34 data35 
#    8.0    9.0    7.5    8.2    3.8    6.3    5.0    2.2    8.8    9.5    7.4    6.2
```

Then subset a color vector `colr` on fifth digit of the names.

```
colr <- c("red", "green", "blue")

op <- par(mar=c(5, 4, 8, 2)+.1, xpd=TRUE)
barplot(dat, main="Three Data Sources Compared",
        names.arg=seq(1:length(dat)),
        col= colr[as.double(substr(names(dat), 5, 5))])
legend(0, 12, unique(substr(names(dat), 1, 5)), col=colr, pch=15, horiz=T, cex=.8)
par(op)
```

#### Gives:

[image]

Comment: An alternative to the named vector may be to use `mget` to get a named list (and, depending on the names of the vectors, hopefully avoid some hardcoding with the naming). `l = mget(ls(pattern = "^data"))`; `v = unlist(l)`; `barplot(v, names.arg = seq_along(v), col = rep(col, lengths(l)))`; `legend(0, 12, names(l), col = col, pch=15, horiz=T)`

Comment: @jay.sf my code seems to trip up on colr object not found, any ideas?

Comment: @user1945827 That's natural because I forgot to include it into the code, see update!

Comment: @jay.sf OK that did the trick.  The other problems on my data set was that my data names were Campaign7, Campaign8 etc... I simply subtracted 6 from within the col vector.  col= colr[(as.double(substr(names(dat), 9, 9)))-6] which put me back on track.

Comment: @user1945827 Yeah of course this is an example to show the idea. If you run into problems with two-digits names, you could also do things such as `v <- c("data91", "data101");gsub("\\d$", "", gsub("data", "", v))` to get the code more robust.

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse solution

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- bind_rows(data1, data2, data3, .id="ID") %>% mutate(X=row_number(), ID2=ID < 3)
# Original plot
d %>% ggplot(aes(x=X, y=Y, fill=ID)) + geom_col() + labs(title="Three datasources compared")
# Using boolean colour
d %>% ggplot(aes(x=X, y=Y, fill=ID2)) + geom_col() + labs(title="Pooling 1st and 2nd datasets")
```

[image]
[image]